# Split column in R to several columns based on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I want to introduce new cols in df based on one column's values.

category col needs to be split on ',' and each split substring needs to go to newly introduced appropriate col.

Minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(category=c('1, 2', '1, 3','3', '2, 3'),
                 othercolumn= c("Grealish", "Saka", "Henry", 'Jesus'))
```

Required df:

```
finaldf <- data.frame(category=c('1, 2', '1, 3','3', '2, 3'),
                      category1=c('1', '1',NA, NA),
                      category2=c('2',NA,NA, '2'),
                      category3=c(NA,'3','3', '3'),
                 othercolumn= c("Grealish", "Saka", "Henry", 'Jesus'))
```

category1, category2, and category3 cols will take values based on the category column, otherwise NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you can do:

Using `strsplt` to split the numbers and convert it to numeric

`setName` the return in `lapply` and `cbind` to data frame

```
nums <- strsplit(df$category, ",") |> 
  type.convert(as.is = T)

cbind(df[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(nums, \(x){
    sq <- seq(max(unlist(nums)))
    ifelse(sq %in% x , sq, NA ) |> 
      setNames(paste0("category", sq))
  })), df[-1])
```

```
  category category1 category2 category3 othercolumn
1     1, 2         1         2        NA    Grealish
2     1, 3         1        NA         3        Saka
3        3        NA        NA         3       Henry
4     2, 3        NA         2         3       Jesus
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `separate` and then `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(df) |> 
  separate_longer_delim(category, delim = ", ") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = category, names_prefix = "category") |> 
  select(starts_with('category'), othercolumn)

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  category1 category2 category3 othercolumn
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      
1 1         2         NA        Grealish   
2 1         NA        3         Saka       
3 NA        NA        3         Henry      
4 NA        2         3         Jesus
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `fastDummies` to create dummy columns and then modify the values

```
library(fastDummies)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 dummy_cols('category', split = ",\\s*") %>% 
 mutate(across(starts_with('category_'), ~ (NA^!.x) * 
     readr::parse_number(cur_column()))) %>%
 relocate(othercolumn, .after = last_col())
```

-output

```
  category category_1 category_2 category_3 othercolumn
1     1, 2          1          2         NA    Grealish
2     1, 3          1         NA          3        Saka
3        3         NA         NA          3       Henry
4     2, 3         NA          2          3       Jesus
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
dcast(
  setDT(df)[
    , strsplit(category, ", "),
    .(category, othercolumn)
  ][
    ,
    V2 := paste0("category_", V1)
  ],
  category + othercolumn ~ V2,
  value.var = "V1"
)
```

which gives

```
   category othercolumn category_1 category_2 category_3
1:     1, 2    Grealish          1          2       <NA>
2:     1, 3        Saka          1       <NA>          3
3:     2, 3       Jesus       <NA>          2          3
4:        3       Henry       <NA>       <NA>          3
```